# UIWindow's makeKeyAndVisible not playing nice with ARC

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I'm recreating some kind of `UIAlertView` specific to my app, so I'm subclassing `UIWindow` to do it. The window gets added to `[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows`, but is never actually shown. I trimmed it down to this small piece of code:

```
UIWindow *testWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
testWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[testWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
```

When I log `[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows`, I see:

```
"<UIWindow: 0x83774f0; frame = (0 0; 320 480); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x8377660>>",
"<UIWindow: 0x8382630; frame = (0 0; 300 400); layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0xf573e60>>"
```

And yet that second window with a blue background color is nowehere to be seen.

**UPDATE**: this seems to be an issue only when ARC is enabled. I created 2 new "single view" projects, one with ARC enabled and the other with ARC disabled. Both are identical and I add the UIWindow code to `viewDidAppear:` of the main view controller. When I run the apps in the simulator, the blue window only shows up in the ARC-disabled project. It looks like ARC gets rid of my UIWindow too quickly and so it doesn't even have time to show up. Making it `__strong` didn't help. Still clueless...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> It looks like ARC gets rid of my UIWindow too quickly and so it doesn't even have time to show up. Making it `__strong` didn't help.

Making what `__strong`? The variable you showed in your question appears to be a local variable, which only exists until the method returns. When the method returns, the variable goes away, so nothing owns the window, so it will then get deallocated.

Assign the window's pointer to a `__strong` instance variable or a `strong` property. Then you'll have a longer-lasting ownership keeping the window alive. Set the ivar or property to `nil` after you dismiss the window.

As a side note, are you sure you want this to be a subclass of UIWindow and not UIView? Even UIAlertView is a view and not a window. If it creates its own window, you may want to do that—have the view create its own window as an implementation detail.

Comment: As you recommended, I ended up making it a UIView subclass which in turn creates its own UIWindow. Making that window a strong property, I rest assured that the window is retained, shown, and removed when I set it to nil. ARC makes much more sense now thanks to you!

Answer (score 0):

1. The docs mention that you should use `UIScreen` to determine the bounds: `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]`
2. I'm not sure it's required, but you're not adding a `UIView` to your window.
3. I noticed the `opaque = NO` - try `[window setOpaque:NO];` or something similar.
4. I tested your code and got:

   > Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

   So basically, use `[window setRootViewController:...];`. Don't ask me why, this really doesn't seem needed to me.

Comment: ... and again :-) This time it should help

Comment: @samvermette: “adding a UIView to your window” should consist of setting the window's `contentView`, not adding a subview. (I'm not sure adding subviews of a window is even supported, though it is technically possible.)

Comment: Re #3: Why would he `setOpaque:NO` if the window is already not opaque?

Comment: @PeterHosey: The normal windows have `opaque = NO`, not the custom ones. That's why I suggested it.

Comment: @PeterHosey `UIWindow` doesn't seem to have a `contentView` property. @Tom my window is getting added outside of the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method (try in viewDidAppear: of the main VC), so I shouldn't need to give it a rootVC...

Comment: See my updated question, this seems to be an issue only happening when ARC is enabled...

Comment: @samvermette: Huh. I thought it did, but I must have misremembered. What you actually need to do is set its `rootViewController`, like Tom says; that VC's view becomes the content view.